# order of columns when creating a compound database index

Tags: database

When creating a compound database index, what should influence the ordering of the fields?

For example suppose I am creating a compound index based on DATE, PRICE, VOLUME what should influence whether I create

```
DATE, PRICE, VOLUME
VOLUME, DATE, PRICE
.
.
.
```

Presumably one will be more suited to particular types of queries but I don't know which queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one will be used if you filter(or search) records by `DATE`, or by `DATE and PRICE`, or by `DATE,PRICE,VOLUME`. It won't be used if you filter records, for instance, by `VOLUME`. The second one will be used for queries where you search condition includes `VOLUME`, or `VOLUME and DATE`, or `VOLUME,DATE,and PRICE`.

To be more precise, indexes can also be used when you use indexed columns in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

Some examples:
Index 1 (`DATE,PRICE,VOLUME`)
Index 2 (`VOLUME,DATE,PRICE`)

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `DATE` = '2011-10-01'; //Index 1 used, Index 2 not used
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `VOLUME` = '111'; //Index 1 not used, Index 2 used
```